# Is it possible to order the filters on the filter pane of Power View?

Tags: filter, powerpivot, office-2013, powerview

I have noticed that the filters added to the filter pane in Power View Reports are automatically ordered by field name, is there a way to rearrange them without changing the field names?

In my case I have diverse date related fields that I want to show first (date, month, year) and then the others, but it doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

> To be exact, I have: **Month, Date, Year, Supervisor, Employee.**
>
> It appears like this: **Date, Employee, Month, Supervisor, Year.**
>
> I want to rearrange them like this: **Year, Month, Date, Supervisor, Employee.**

I have read the topics about filters and the filter pane for Power View in Microsoft.com (http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/filtering-in-power-view-HA104040684.aspx) but it doesn't say anything about ordering the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Power View doesn't allow a lot of control over things like field and filter ordering at the moment.  They will be displayed in alphabetical order, by field name.

Fortunately, one thing we do have control over is the field names in your Power Pivot model.  So, while it definitely doesn't solve the problem properly, you could work around it if you're willing to rename your fields.

If you rename your existing fields: **Month, Date, Year, Supervisor, Employee**

Like this: **2: Month, 3: Date, 1: Year, 4: Supervisor, 5: Employee**

They will display in the desired order: **1: Year, 2: Month, 3: Date, 4: Supervisor, 5: Employee**

It's definitely not perfect, and it's a bit of a hack, but it will at least let you control the ordering, albeit through alphabetic wizardry.  Bear in mind though, that with it being ordered as strings, 10 will appear before 2 (i.e. 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and so on).

Comment: Thank you GShenanigan. My problem with that approach is that on the graphs the names show those numbers, I guess there is no way to hide them there without hiding the whole field name, right?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.  Like I said, it's a hacky workaround, rather than a proper solution.  Power View doesn't (yet) allow control of series labels like SSRS does.